# Importing non-root module from multiple non-root binaries

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I am learning Rust and decided to write a simple client/server program. Both the client and the server will be using a very simple module I've already written. Knowing that this code might grow, I decided to compartmentalize my source for clarity. Right now my current hierarchy looks as follows:

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── client
│   │   └── main.rs
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── communicate.rs
│   │   └── mod.rs
│   ├── lib.rs
│   └── server
│       └── main.rs
```

[Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596920/split-a-module-across-several-files) [of](http://blog.thiago.me/notes-about-rust-modules/) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922091/how-do-you-use-parent-module-imports-in-rust) examples I found on Stack Overflow and the net provide great samples for when the `main.rs` is in the project root directory. Unfortunately I'm trying to do something different as shown above.

`communicate.rs` contains all of the network code I have written. Eventually I will add other Rust files here and include their `public mod` statement in `mod.rs`. Currently `common/mod.rs` all I have is 
`pub mod communicate;`

Focusing on just the `client` folder, all I have is `main.rs` as shown. The file "header" lists

```
extern crate common;

use std::thread;
use std::time;
use std::net;
use std::mem;

use common::communicate;

pub fn main() {
   // ...
}
```

Besides the fundamental `[package]` section, all I have in `Cargo.toml` is

```
[[bin]]
name = "server"
path = "src/server/main.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "client"
path = "src/client/main.rs"
```

When I try to build the client binary, the compiler complains that the `common` crate could not be found.

```
$ cargo build 
   Compiling clientserver v0.1.0 (file:///home/soplu/rust/RustClientServer)
client/main.rs:1:1: 1:21 error: can't find crate for `common` [E0463]
client/main.rs:1 extern crate common;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
error: Could not compile `clientserver`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I think this is because it is looking for a common crate within the `client/` folder. I had this same problem when I tried the `mod` statement instead of `extern crate` statement.

```
use std::thread;
use std::time;
use std::net;
use std::mem;

mod common;
```

Gave me:

```
client/main.rs:6:5: 6:11 error: file not found for module `common`
client/main.rs:6 mod common;
                     ^~~~~~
client/main.rs:6:5: 12:11 help: name the file either common.rs or common/mod.rs inside the directory "client"
```

I also tried (using the `extern crate...`) adding a `lib.rs` in the `client` whose contents are `pub mod common;` but I still get the same error as the first.

One potential solution I found to model it like [this project](https://github.com/matthiasbeyer/imag), but this would require a `Cargo.toml` in every folder, something which I'd like to avoid.

I feel like I am close but am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not building `common` as a crate right now. The crates being built are the library `clientserver` (the default name for the library is the package name) and the binaries `client` and `server`.

Normally, `extern crate clientserver;` should work. However, if you want to name your library differently, you can do so by specifying a different name in a [`[lib]` section in Cargo.toml](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#configuring-a-target). In this section, you can also specify a different source path for the library's main source file. In your case, it will probably be better, otherwise you'll end up with a crate named `common` and all of its contents would be in a module named `common`, so you'd have to access everything as `common::common::foo`. For example, by adding this to your Cargo.toml:

```
[lib]
name = "common"
path = "src/common/lib.rs"
```

you could combine `src/lib.rs` and `src/common/mod.rs` into `src/common/lib.rs`. Then, `extern crate common;` should work in your binaries.

Comment: Perfect, this solved my problem. Your very first statement actually helped a lot in clearing what I was trying to produce. Thank you. Could I declare multiple libraries using that same method? Akin to 

`[lib]`
`name = "otherlib"`
`path = "src/otherlib/lib.rs"`

Comment: Cargo only supports one library per package. You can reference local packages in Cargo.toml with [path dependencies](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies).