# How to include types from the main module in other files from the same crate?

Tags: module, rust

I'm writing a Rust library called `my_new_lib` and have the following file structure:

```
├── my_new_lib
    ├── src
        ├── lib.rs
        └── file1.rs
    ├── tests
```

In `lib.rs` I defined a struct:

```rust
/// content of lib.rs

pub struct my_struct {}
```

In `file1.rs` I want to use `my_struct`, for example:

```rust
/// content of file1.rs

use ????

pub struct my_second_struct {
    member1: my_struct
}
```

what should I put in the `use` clause in `file1.rs` to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use one module from another module in a Rust cargo project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071513/how-to-use-one-module-from-another-module-in-a-rust-cargo-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use parent module imports in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922091/how-do-you-use-parent-module-imports-in-rust)

Comment: @hellow The answer must be updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the valid path roots in the use keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289071/what-are-the-valid-path-roots-in-the-use-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `crate` keyword to access to the root of your crate:

```
use crate::MyStruct;
```