# What are the valid path roots in the use keyword?

Tags: module, rust, rust-2018

With the module system being revamped for the 2018 edition, the functioning of the `use` keyword has changed. What are the valid paths that can go after the `use` keyword?

Answer (score 4):

Paths in `use` statements can only start in the following ways:

- *name of an extern crate*: then it refers to that extern crate
- `crate`: refers to the (top level of your) own crate
- `self`: refers to the current module
- `super`: refers to the parent module
- *other name*: in this case, it looks for that name *relative* to the current module

An example demonstrating all kinds of `use`-paths ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=370cfbc657f0946fa738a220f641aa30)):

```
pub const NAME: &str = "peter";
pub const WEIGHT: f32 = 3.1;

mod inner {
    mod child {
        pub const HEIGHT: f32 = 0.3;
        pub const AGE: u32 = 3;
    }

    // Different kinds of uses
    use base64::encode;   // Extern crate `base64`
    use crate::NAME;      // Own crate (top level module)
    use self::child::AGE; // Current module
    use super::WEIGHT;    // Parent module (in this case, this is the same 
                          // as `crate`)
    use child::HEIGHT;    // If the first name is not `crate`, `self` or 
                          // `super` and it's not the name of an extern 
                          // crate, it is a path relative to the current
                          // module (as if it started with `self`)
}
```

This `use` statement behavior changed with Rust 2018 (available in Rust ≥ 1.31)). Read [this guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html) for more information about use statements and how they changed in Rust 2018.

Answer (score 2):

Your path can begin in 2 different ways: absolute or relative:

- Your path can begin with a crate name, or the `crate` keyword to name the current crate:

  ```
  struct Foo;

  mod module {
      use crate::Foo; // Use `Foo` from the current crate.
      use serde::Serialize; // Use `Serialize` from the serde crate.
  }

  fn main() {}
  ```
- Otherwise, the root is implicitely `self`, that means that your path will be relative to your current module:

  ```
  mod module {
      pub struct Foo;
      pub struct Bar;
  }

  use module::Foo; // By default, you are in the `self` (current) module.
  use self::module::Bar; // Explicit `self`.
  ```

  In this context, you can use `super` to access to the outer module:

  ```
  struct Foo;

  mod module {
      use super::Foo; // Access `Foo` from the outer module.
  }
  ```

Comment: A leading `::` is also permitted, which is equivalent to `crate::`. Some people think it's ugly, but it's used a lot in code that precedes edition 2018, which is when `crate::` was introduced.

Comment: @PeterHall Are you sure? It does not compile

Comment: Oh, I see. I will modify the question to target the 2018 edition.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even realise that no longer works in edition 2018!