# use module inside module from src folder

Tags: rust

I want to separate the application logic to keep my main.rs file clean. I am using diesel for a simple project and I have the following files inside /src folder

- **main.rs**
- *lib.rs*
- *models.rs*
- *schema.rs*

I tried declaring the modules inside *main.rs* file and using them in the *lib.rs* file but that produces the following error:

> unresolved import `models`; no `models` external crate [E0432]

**main.rs** looks like this:

```
pub mod lib;
pub mod schema;
pub mod models;
```

**lib.rs** produces error with this:

```
pub use models;
pub use schema::sent_sms;
```

I do not understand why things need to be so awfully complicated in this language, or maybe I am too stupid to understand it.
Please help me understand.

Comment: [Minimal example to reproduce the error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fde9a8b3939a937d601b2879d89817ba). That's really not a helpful error message :/  (it get's better if you use something from that module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**The main part of this answer was moved to the duplicate question!**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577897/2408867)

So your problem is that `use models;` looks for `models` relative to the current module (`lib`). But `models` is not a sub module of `lib`, but of `main`. So the **correct way to refer to these top level modules** is like that:

```
use crate::{
    models,
    schema::sent_sms,
};
```

---

Additional notes:

- If you have a executable project and just need a module to have some utility functions in, you usually wouldn't call it `lib` as that name is the default name for library crates' roots.
- This `use` statement behavior changed with Rust 2018 (≥ 1.31))
- Read [this guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html) for more information about use statements and how they changed in Rust 2018