# How to include a file/module at the same level?

Tags: rust

I am using Rust 2018 with the following file structure:

```
src/main.rs
src/types.rs
src/compute.rs
```

`types.rs` contains `pub struct Entity {}`.

I have no issue including `types` and `compute` in `main.rs`:

```
mod types;
mod compute;
```

I want to import `types` inside `compute.rs`:

```
mod types;
// or
pub mod types;
```

I get:

```
file not found for module types
```

I tried to follow [path clarity](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html) in the edition guide without success.

The examples never refer to a **same level import** that is not from `main.rs` or `lib.rs`

I tried to specify the path using:

```
#[path = "types.rs"] mod types;
```

Then I get this error:

```
expected type `compute::types::Entity`
              found type `types::Entity`
```

It seems it is redefining the module `types` inside my module `compute`.

I cannot use the `use` keyword since it is not an external crate.

I took a look at [file hierarchy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/split.html) in Rust by Example but there is no same level import.

I am trying to avoid having `mod.rs` like in Rust 2015.

1. Is there a way to do this **same level** import?
2. Is my file structure the issue?
3. What file structure would be better?

Comment: *I want to import to types inside compute.rs* — in **addition** to or **instead of** importing `types` in main?

Comment: Importing types in compute in addition of main

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30677258/155423); [What are the valid path roots in the use keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54289071/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: in *compute.rs*, add `use crate::types::Entity;`

Comment: Looks like the `use super::types;` did the trick.