# How to import file from sibling folder in Rust

Tags: rust

```
src/renderers/smart_video_renderer.rs
src/shaders/video_vertex.rs
```

I want to use `video_vertex.rs` in `smart_video_renderer.rs`. I tried:

```
use super::shaders::video_vertex::*
```

or

```
use shaders::video_vertex::*
```

but it won't import anyway.

I tried [How do you use parent module imports in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922091/how-do-you-use-parent-module-imports-in-rust) on which according to, it should be just `use two::two;` or in my case `use shaders::shaders::...` so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main.rs or lib.rs you need to declare `shaders` module with:

```
pub mod shaders;
```

And then inside shaders folder you need a mod.rs file with:

```
pub mod video_vertex;
```

Then you can use it inside src/renderers/smart_video_renderer.rs with:

```
use crate::shaders::video_vertex::*;
```