# error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `std` only shows up once

Tags: rust

This is an error I get when I try to run `cargo test` in a project. What does it mean? How do I fix it?

I can try to update with more details, but I could not reproduce it with a minimal example, unfortunately...

Full error:

```
cargo test
   Compiling ranges v0.1.0 (file:///Users/user/code/rust-project)
error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `std` only shows up once
  |
  = help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away

error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `core` only shows up once
  |
  = help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away

error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `collections` only shows up once
  |
  = help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away

error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `rustc_unicode` only shows up once
  |
  = help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away

error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `alloc` only shows up once
  |
  = help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away

error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `rand` only shows up once
  |
  = help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away

error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `libc` only shows up once
  |
  = help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away

error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `unwind` only shows up once
  |
  = help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away

error: cannot satisfy dependencies so `panic_unwind` only shows up once
  |
  = help: having upstream crates all available in one format will likely make this go away

error: cannot link together two allocators: alloc_jemalloc and alloc_system

error: aborting due to 10 previous errors
```

It happens during the compilation step when I try to run tests that use the crate through an `extern crate`, like here: [How do I access files in the src directory from files in my tests directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305337/how-do-i-access-files-in-the-src-directory-from-files-in-my-tests-directory/40305523#40305523)

On OS X, `rustc 1.12.0 (3191fbae9 2016-09-23)`

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19680, looks to me like a usability bug.

Comment: If that fixes it, should I let the q stand? Will check back after the weekend, gotta run :)

Comment: Certainly, a clear question on StackOverflow may be easier to find and a clear answer may be able to elaborate more.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to Matthieu M. for pointing me to the correct [github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19680)!

The fix was to put the following in my `Cargo.toml`:

```
crate-type = ["rlib", "dylib"]
```

If you are using `rustc` the option

```
-C prefer-dynamic
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: how to do this using cargo build in moden, 2022, rust?

Comment: @realtebo `cargo rustc -- -C prefer-dynamic` still works today.

Comment: thanks! No available method to pass this flag when using `cargo build` ?

Comment: @realtebo you can set it either via `RUSTFLAGS='-C prefer-dynamic' cargo build` or specifying it in `.cargo/config` - https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html